# Google Tag Manager shows Invalid or missing account ID in Google Tag Assistant Legacy

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

I have used react-gtm-module in the react application, but Google tag manager still gives an Invalid or missing account ID error, I have attached my code below, please help

[image: chrome inspect element]

[image: the extension]

[image: my code]

Answer (score 0):

It's about the new GTM ID that's now 8 characters. The Tag Assistant extension does not recognise it presently (great job Google) but it should still track correctly.